# Regex: Match a word not surrounded by other letters and only include the word in the result

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my current regular expression: `/[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo](?![A-Za-z0-9\-])(?![^<]*>)/g`

This is my test for matching:

```
hello helloa ahello <hello>
^^^^^        !!!!!!
Should match ^^^^^ only
```

My current regex matches `!!!!!` as well. I made a regular expression that looks like this: `/(?<![A-Za-z0-9\-])[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo](?![A-Za-z0-9\-])(?![^<]*>)/g` but lookbehinds are not supported in javascript, so I don't know what to do.

EDIT: I think that posting the project will help, so [this is what I'm working on.](http://users.lk.net/~vityav/schoolsites/editingtool.html)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's a little confusing, do you mind explaining?

Comment: From your code, I guessed you wanted to match a whole word `hello` that is not a part of a compound word and only replace it outside `<...>` substrings. Try [`s.replace(/(<[^>]*>)|(-)?\b(hello)\b(?!-)/gi, function($0,$1,$2,$3) { return $1 ? $0 : ($2 ? $0 : "!!!"+$3+"!!!");})`](https://jsfiddle.net/ma9seau9/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Here I search for `hello` where it has to have at least a whitespace character at either side, or the beginning or end of string.

So in my example I've added a couple extra hello's, just test for the start & end of lines too.

```js
var re = /(^|\s)(hello)(\s|$)/g;

var str = 'hello helloa ahello hello <hello> hello';

console.log(str.replace(re, "$1!!$2!!$3"));
```

Comment: That's great but I can't match the space character

Comment: @zevee I've updated to do multiple capture groups, and to show it I've used replace to wrap the hello's in `!!`

Comment: I've put it into my code (linked above) and it seemed not to highlight anything...